# PHP ImageMagick 7.0 lacks some Methods

Tags: php, imagick

Scenario is the following, in my local machine with Ubuntu 18 and a older version of Imagick I'm running the following small script:

```
<?php
$imageX = new Imagick();
print_r( $imageX::getVersion() );
echo "<pre>";print_r(get_class_methods($imageX));
```

Result :
Array ( [versionNumber] => 1687 [versionString] => ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 )

Array
(
    [0] => optimizeimagelayers -> with 371 methods
)

Now since I wanted to some special functions and I discovered they where not on my Amazon AMI server, I installed latest version on the remote test:
 slosarek.eu /api/web-image/imagick.php

Array ( [versionNumber] => 1800 [versionString] => ImageMagick 7.0.8-7 Q16 x86_64 2018-07-23)

Array
(
    [0] => optimizeimagelayers  -> 341 Methods
)

Also there are about 30 Methods that are missing in the new version vs 6.9.7-4. For example: 
orderedPosterizeImage() is not there
DITHER also not there (I'm trying to convert some grayscale pictures in 1 bit to display stuff in Eink)

I'm for sure missing something! PHP version is PHP 7.0.30
I would love to discover what is the issue here or if it's just that the new versions of Imagick have less Methods and I'm just missing the news.

Comment: Before posting to Stackoverflow, you probably should have taken a moment to read the imagemagick changelog, because that's where you look at what may have changed and why. If it's not in there, then you have something to ask, but it's in there.

Comment: Perhaps this is still there and might help with your grayscale to 1 bit dithering. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/imagick.quantizeimage.php

Comment: I checked the changelog, but I understood they where only some functions removed for PHP 7.0 not that there where removed permanently. Actually I'm not finding an easy replace for some stuff I did on last version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those functions has been removed from / not ported over from IM6 to ImageMagick 7. You can see the note [about being deprecated in the PHP7 build](https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/blob/master/ChangeLog) of the PHP imagick module as well:

> 3.4.3RC1
>   - Fixes:
>     * Imagick::transformImage and Imagick::orderedPosterizeImage now correctly excluded from 
>     IM7 build.

Comment: Also see http://imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#cli for the IM 7 deprecation functions. Most are still allowed, but may get removed at some later time. Many have IM 7 equivalents with different names, such as matte being replace with alpha. I do not know much about Imagick changes for version 7 of ImageMagick.

Comment: What I still didn't found is how to do Dithering like you did in 6, for example converting a grayscale image to 1 bit and have this effect. I actually find myself quite lost with this new version...I have to learn it again ;)